# Playing WAV audio from a Memory Stream in Android

Tags: android, audio, xamarin.android, wav

I will receive very short pieces of audio data from a REST service. They will arrive in WAV format. I then need to play them on the Android device. 
I want to do this without saving the data to file - it just makes it more complex than it needs to be. However I can't get it to work from a memory stream. Below is the test code I am using (using a .wav file in the assets folder):

```
public void PlayAudioFile(string fileName)
    {
        bool useMemoryStream = true;

        if (useMemoryStream)
        {
            //this doesn't work
            MemoryStream ms = GetMS(fileName);
            byte[] msData = new byte[ms.Length];
            ms.Position = 0;
            ms.Read(msData, 0, (int)ms.Length);
            String base64EncodedString = Base64.EncodeToString(msData, Base64Flags.Default);

            String url = "data:audio/wav;base64," + base64EncodedString;
            MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();

            player.Prepared += (s, e) =>
            {
                player.Start();
            };

            player.SetDataSource(url);
            player.Prepare();
        }
        else
        {
            //this works
            MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();

            var fd = global::Android.App.Application.Context.Assets.OpenFd(fileName);
            player.Prepared += (s, e) =>
            {
                player.Start();
            };

            player.SetDataSource(fd.FileDescriptor, fd.StartOffset, fd.Length);
            player.Prepare();
        }
    }

    private MemoryStream GetMS(string fileName)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        Context context = Android.App.Application.Context;

        using (System.IO.Stream stream = context.Assets.Open(fileName))
        {
            stream.CopyTo(ms);
        }

        return ms;
    }
```

When I play it from file it is fine, but the memory stream approach gives me a IOException Prepare Failed error. I suspect the problem might be with the audio/wav value. I can't find any documentation for supported values for this. When I try this with a MP3 file and change it to audio/mp3 it works fine from a memory stream.
Any ideas!

Comment: You can use https://github.com/martijn00/VlcXamarin from nuegt .It support playing all formats of video.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [AudioTrack](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack).

In this case you can specify audio parameters for your wav file:

- SampleRate in HZ
- Encoding type(for example 8bit or 16bit pcm)
- Channel(Mono\Stereo)

Then setup buffer size and transfer mode.
Call play.

Example:

```
    int minBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(16000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    track =  new AudioTrack.Builder().setAudioFormat(new AudioFormat.Builder()
                                        .setChannelMask(AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO)
                                        .setEncoding(AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)
                                        .setSampleRate(44100)
                                        .build())
                                .setTransferMode(AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM)
                                .setBufferSizeInBytes(minBufferSize)
                                .build();
track.play();
```

If everything is ok. You can start write your data to buffer(use background thread for that).

```
 int size = 512;//(for example)
 byte[] veryShortPiecesOfAudioAataFromRESTService = new byte[size];
 track.write(veryShortPiecesOfAudioAataFromRESTService, 0, size);
```